# useState or useRef for form submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Normally when I handle form submits, I use `useState` for input values and set `onChange` event as

```
const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({
    title: "",
    address: "init"
  });

  function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const meetupData = {
      meetupTitle: inputValues.title,
    };

    console.log(meetupData);
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="title">Meetup Title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          id="title"
          value={inputValues.title}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setInputValues({ ...inputValues, title: e.target.value })
          }
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Add Meetup</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
```

but in some tutorial I found out it's written using `useRef` as

```
const titleInputRef = useRef();

  function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const enteredTitle = titleInputRef.current.value;

    const meetupData = {
      title: enteredTitle,
    };

    console.log(meetupData);
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="title">Meetup Title</label>
        <input type="text" required id="title" ref={titleInputRef} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Add Meetup</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
```

and I am trying to understand what's the difference and which one could be better in general performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use state based approach (aka [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) components) or  ref based approach (aka [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#alternatives-to-controlled-components) components) depending on the situation, although react recommends to use state based approach most of the time.

Here is comparison between the two.

With state based approach you get all the benefits you get when you store something in state:

- If you you keep form values in state you can more easily react to their changes during a re-render, for example disable some button when value of another form field is empty.
- You can more easily pass them around as props to other components.

However, these are disadvantages of state based approach:

- You need to type a bit more code
- Your component will re-render each time you change form value, because you are also changing something in state.

Answer (score 1):

By purpose, if you use useState, you get both a `getter` and a `setter`(which triggers rerender to update the value immediately), while if you use useRef you only get a `getter`.

Hence, if you use useRef, you do not need to set `value={state}`, while useState does.

In general, if you want to validate values input from user (e.g. with onChange event) you have to use `useState`, if you only want to get the value on submission of the form, you are free to use useRef.